# Edit an entity with Symfony 6 Form System: how can I tweak the entity-loading logic?

Tags: symfony-forms

**TL;DR**: how can I use a custom Doctrine query to load the entity from the database witg Symfony 6.3 form system?

**Longer version**

I've a simple form to UPDATE a phone number in an `Opportunity` entity:

```php
class OpportunityChangePhoneType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder
            ->add("accessKey")
            ->add("mobilePhone")
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Opportunity::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Such entity maps an `opportunity` database table like this:

```
id|access_key       |mobile_phone|
--+-----------------+------------+
 1|96783f217481f....|111         |
 2|a967e4017f06f....|555         |
 3|14697aeb49602....|333         |
```

As you can see, I don't expose the `id` in the Form, but I use the `accessKey` instead.

On the updating controller, I have:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(OpportunityChangePhoneType::class);
$form->handleRequest($this->request);

if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {

  $opportunity = $form->getData();
  $this->em->getRepository(Opportunity::class)->save($opportunity, true);
}
```

The problem is that `createForm` doesn't know how to load the `Opportunity` entity from the access_key field, so I always get a new entity instead of updating the old one.

How can I provide a custom logic to load the entity properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stopgap solution, I manually loaded the Opportunity entity and then I passed it to `createForm()`

```php
$accessKey = $this->request->get("accessKey");
// ... check if the accessKey format is valid ...
$opportunity = $this->em->getRepository(Opportunity::class)->findOneBy(["accessKey" => $accessKey]);
// ... check if the $opportunity is valid (not expired, deleted, disabled, ...) ...
$form = $this->createForm(OpportunityChangePhoneType::class, $opportunity);
....
```

It works, but it partially defeats the purpose of the Form System.

**Update**: the mighty Ryan Weaver himself [confirmed](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-forms/custom-entity-type-query#comment-31109) that this is a valid approach.